# Multiple photos with the same dimensions

Tags: html, css

I would like to build a website for an exhibition but i don't really know how to make multiple photos have the same dimension without losing the quality.
For example look at this guy's website: https://www.peterdraws.com/shop/. I want my photos to look like here.

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="work">
          <a href="#"><div class="boxx"><div class="box" style="background: 
             url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center ; 
             -webkit-background-size: contain;
             -moz-background-size: contain;
             -o-background-size: contain;
             background-size: contain;">
          </div></div></a>
          <a href="#"><div class="boxx"><div class="box" style="background: 
             url('img1.jpg') no-repeat center center ; 
             -webkit-background-size: contain;
             -moz-background-size: contain;
             -o-background-size: contain;
             background-size: contain;">
          </div></div></a>
    </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
    .work {
          width: 75%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 40px 0 70px 0;
    }

    .work .boxx {
          width: 350px;
          height: 400px;
          display: table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .work .boxx .box {
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make images of different dimension *look* like they are the same dimension, try using `cover` for `background-size` instead of `contain`:

```
<div class="work">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="boxx">
            <div class="box" style="background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="boxx">
            <div class="box" style="background: url('img1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

This of course means that parts of the images have to be cut off (just like on the example website you provided). To control which parts are visible, look into what values the `background-position` CSS property accepts.

For more information on `background-size` and `background-position`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: Yeah, i already tried it but if i use cover some parts of the images will be cut off.

Comment: How else would you make images that are not the same dimension have the same dimensions? You have to cut off parts of the images in order to achieve the same dimension, the relevant question is _which_ parts to cut off.

Comment: I thought it is possible without having to cutt off parts of the images. And now that you said which parts to cut off, can you choose?

Comment: You should play around with the values in `style="background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center;`, specifically try replacing the `center` value with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`; or use percentage values.